# elastic search select fields to return in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I select what fields get returned in an aggregation bucket?

I have a bunch of fields in my data like

```
Document:{
"contenthash": "0a12ac12ac12ac12ac12ac12"
"time": "01:01:01"
"Content": "hello"
}
```

When I aggregate on the content hash, I get a bucket containing just the content hash and not the other fields. What I want to be able to do is return all fields associated with that content hash. So I have:

```
"buckets": {
"key"  :{ "0a12ac12ac12ac12ac12ac12":
"time" : "01:01:01"
"Content" : "hello"}
```

I know I can do a sub aggregation to get to the data under the content hash, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html).

If you designed your aggregation to be something like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "byHash" : {
      "terms": {
        "field" : "contenthash"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would then see, for each unique *contenthash*, the most relevant source documents that were aggregated in that *contenthash* bucket.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's possible to apply a sort on on the top_hits that are returned? I would like it so that all hits returned get sorted by a field. I've tried using the sort function of top_hits, however I think that only applies within a bucket and not across all buckets. Thanks!

Comment: @ADev, good question, I looked into this and I can't see a way to sort all the top_hits across all the buckets. This is probably something you'll need to do in your application.